# How can i move or copy files (or folder) from solaris server to removable disk.(Backup Tape drive)

Tags: linux, perl, unix, backup, awk

I need to move or copy some zip(.tar,.gz,.Z) files from Solaris server to backup tape drive. I also  want to retrieve from tape drive whenever I want without any loss.

Kindly explain the procedure. I have less knowledge in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "howto tape backup solaris" found this:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/solaris-tar-command-to-backup-data-on-tape-device.html

PS: Computer hardware and also its environment is not perfect so you cannot rule out loss but only achive a low loss probability.